# ReactJS auth not working, redirect to login page fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-v4

I implemented the private routes in the react project, but I did not find the error that causes the authentication to fail. Redirection is not working, debugging does not enter the function estaAutenticado.

Token is a const retrieved from sessionStorage.

The endpoint /usuario makes validation from JWT token.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './servicos/Rotas';

ReactDOM.render(<Routes/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Rotas.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { estaAutenticado } from "./Autenticacao";
import App from '../App';
import Login from '../Login';
import SelecionarFiliais from '../SelecionarFiliais';

export const rotas = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    icon: null,
    component: Login,
    private: false,
    exact: false
  },
  {
    path: "/selecionar_filiais",
    name: "Login",
    icon: null,
    component: SelecionarFiliais,
    private: true,
    exact: false
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: null,
    component: App,
    private: true,
    exact: true
  }
];

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest} render={props =>
        estaAutenticado() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);

const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {rotas.map((e) => (
            e.private ? <Route key={e.path} exact={e.exact} path={e.path} component={e.component}/> : <PrivateRoute key={e.path} exact={e.exact} path={e.path} component={e.component}/>
          ))}
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

**function estaAutenticado()**

```
export const estaAutenticado = async () => {
    let result = false
    if (token !== null){
        result = await API.post('/usuario')
        .then(function(response) {
            return true
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            return false
        });
        return result
    }
    return result
};
```

Any help, please!!! Thanks

Comment: `props =>  estaAutenticado() ? ...` doesn't work like you expect it to. When that is called by React, it returns a pending Promise (and thus will always render the Component, not the Route)

Comment: Hm... I'm new to js / react and the subject of Promises / Await / Async is new to me. From what I read quickly, I need to manage the estaAutenticado response with a new function, which would be my Promise?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this opened my mind.

Answer (score 3):

```
result = await API.post('/usuario')
        .then(function(response) {
            return true
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            return false
        });
        return result
```

Should be

```
try {
 result = await API.post('/usuario')
 return result
} catch(e) {
 return false
}
```

Edit:

Also your mapping if function is inverted:

```
{rotas.map((e) => (
            e.private ? <Route key={e.path} exact={e.exact} path={e.path} component={e.component}/> : <PrivateRoute key={e.path} exact={e.exact} path={e.path} component={e.component}/>
          ))}
```

Should be

```
{rotas.map((e) => (
            !e.private ? <Route key={e.path} exact={e.exact} path={e.path} component={e.component}/> : <PrivateRoute key={e.path} exact={e.exact} path={e.path} component={e.component}/>
          ))}
```

If it is private, so render the PrivateRoute.

Comment: exactly what I was going to suggest!